# how to time-out gracefully while downloading with python

Tags: python, exception, download

I'm downloading a huge set of files with following code in a loop:

```
try:
    urllib.urlretrieve(url2download, destination_on_local_filesystem)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    break
except:
    print "Timed-out or got some other exception: "+url2download
```

If the server times-out on URL url2download when connection is just initiating, the last exception is handled properly. But sometimes server responded, and downloading is started, but the server is so slow, that it'll takes hours for even one file, and eventually it returns something like:

```
Enter username for Clients Only at albrightandomalley.com:
Enter password for  in Clients Only at albrightandomalley.com:
```

and just hangs there (although no username/passworde is aksed if the same link is downloaded through the browser).

My intention in this situation would be -- skip this file and go to the next one. The question is -- how to do that? Is there a way in python to specify how long is OK to work on downloading one file, and if more time is already spent, interrupt, and go forward?

Comment: What you are seeing there is the server ask for authentication. By default `urllib.urlretrieve()` will prompt the user to enter a username and password. If you want to avoid this, you can create a new class derived from `urllib.FancyURLOpener` and handle this "error" yourself.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

`import socket`

`socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)`

Comment: Can you give one example to use?

Answer (score 4):

If you're not limited to what's shipped with python out of the box, then the [urlgrabber](http://linux.duke.edu/projects/urlgrabber/) module might come in handy:

```
import urlgrabber
urlgrabber.urlgrab(url2download, destination_on_local_filesystem,
                   timeout=30.0)
```

Comment: urlgrabber link no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

There's a discussion of this [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#sockets-and-layers).  Caveats (in addition to the ones they mention): I haven't tried it, and they're using `urllib2`, not `urllib` (would that be a problem for you?)  (Actually, now that I think about it, this technique would probably work for `urllib`, too).

Answer (score 2):

This question is more general about timing out a function:
[How to limit execution time of a function call in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-limit-execution-time-of-a-function-call-in-python)

I've used the method described in my answer there to write a wait for text function that times out to attempt an auto-login.  If you'd like similar functionality you can reference the code here:

http://code.google.com/p/psftplib/source/browse/trunk/psftplib.py