# Timeout a file download with Python urllib?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

Python beginner here. I want to be able to timeout my download of a video file if the process takes longer than 500 seconds.

```
import urllib
try:
   urllib.urlretrieve ("http://www.videoURL.mp4", "filename.mp4")
except Exception as e:
   print("error")
```

How do I amend my code to make that happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600848/how-to-time-out-gracefully-while-downloading-with-python

Answer (score 18):

Better way is to use `requests` so you can stream the results and easily check for timeouts:

```
import requests

# Make the actual request, set the timeout for no data to 10 seconds and enable streaming responses so we don't have to keep the large files in memory
request = requests.get('http://www.videoURL.mp4', timeout=10, stream=True)

# Open the output file and make sure we write in binary mode
with open('filename.mp4', 'wb') as fh:
    # Walk through the request response in chunks of 1024 * 1024 bytes, so 1MiB
    for chunk in request.iter_content(1024 * 1024):
        # Write the chunk to the file
        fh.write(chunk)
        # Optionally we can check here if the download is taking too long
```

Answer (score 14):

Although `urlretrieve` does not have this feature, you can still set the default timeout (in seconds) for all new socket objects.

```
import socket
import urllib    

socket.setdefaulttimeout(15)

try:
   urllib.urlretrieve ("http://www.videoURL.mp4", "filename.mp4")
except Exception as e:
   print("error")
```

Answer (score 3):

`urlretrieve` does not have that option. But you can easily perform your example with the help of `urlopen` and writing the result in a file, like so:

```
request = urllib.urlopen("http://www.videoURL.mp4", timeout=500)
with open("filename.mp4", 'wb') as f:
    try:
        f.write(request.read())
    except:
        print("error")
```

That's if you are using Python 3. If you are using Python 2, you should rather use urllib2.

Comment: urlopen can be easy, but for a large file. request.read() can be slow and take forever, you should consider adding a timeout around that function, probably using singal package.

Comment: Not only can it be slow, it could fail completely. For example, suppose the file is 10GB in size, and won't fit in memory.

Comment: `Also note that the urllib.request.urlopen() function in Python 3 is equivalent to urllib2.urlopen() and that urllib.urlopen() has been removed.` The correct call in 3.6 is `urllib.request.urlopen()`. I don't know if maybe there is a Python version where `urllib.urlopen()` actually works, so I won't edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made two wrapper functions for retrieving from the web with a specific number of retries and the amount of timeout

```
class DownloadUnsuccessful(socket.timeout):
    pass

def web2soup(url, tries=9, timeout=30, sleepBetween=1):
    failures = 0
    while True:
        if failures == tries:
            raise DownloadUnsuccessful()
        try:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as con:
                content = con.read().decode('utf-8')
                break
        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
            raise DownloadUnsuccessful()
        except urllib.error.URLError:
            time.sleep(sleepBetween)
        except TimeoutError:
            pass
        except socket.timeout:
            pass
        
        failures += 1
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def web2file(url, filePath, tries=9, timeout=30, sleepBetween=1, tempExt='.temporary_filename'):
    tempPath = filePath + tempExt
    
    failures = 0
    while True:
        if failures == tries:
            try:
                os.remove(tempPath)
            except:
                pass
            raise DownloadUnsuccessful()
        try:
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, tempPath)
            break
        except urllib.error.HTTPError:
            raise DownloadUnsuccessful()
        except urllib.error.URLError:
            time.sleep(sleepBetween)
        except TimeoutError:
            pass
        except socket.timeout:
            pass

    
    fileExt = os.path.splitext(url)[1]
    filePath = filePath+fileExt
    os.rename(tempPath, filePath)
    
    return filePath
```

This way i can just call them and know what exception to expect if something goes wrong.