# urllib.request.urlretrieve hangs on failure in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

Referring to the following code in python 3 to download an image from url-

```
import urllib.request
try:
    print('entering urlretrieve')
    # If connection failed after entering the function urllib.request.urlretrieve()
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('img_url','temp_location')
    print('exited urlretrieve')
except:
    print('connection problem')
print('program ended')
```

Now, **problem** is if connection fails inside urllib.request.urlretrieve() then the program simply waits and do nothing

Output in this case is -

> entering urlretrieve.

But, my **requirement** is to terminate printing -

> connection problem

when exception occur inside this function.

Please Help!

Comment: Is your requirement "connection failed" a typo for 'connection problem'?

Comment: you were correct, I have fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line at the top of your code

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(15)
```

Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32763720/timeout-a-file-download-with-python-urllib) if you want to learn more