# What does [x]* mean in python function documention?

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing, documentation, urllib

I want to specify a timeout parameter for urllib.request.urlopen in python 3.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) say:

> `urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None, [timeout, ]*, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)`

What does `[timeout, ]*` mean?

I thought that all optional, named arguments (`data=None`, `cafile=None` ...) had to appear before all un-named arguments.

It looks here like `timeout` is an un-named argument. But it appears *after* `data`.

Looking just at that documentation, I have no idea whether to use:

- `urlopen(url, 123)`
- `urlopen(url, timeout=123)`
- `urlopen(url, [123])`
- `urlopen(url, [123]*)`

I can see from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32764162/5443120) that the correct answer is `urlopen(url, timeout=123)`.
But if that's the case, why do the docs say `[timeout, ]*`, why not just `timeout=None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of independent features - square brackets and asterisk.

`[timeout, ]` means that `timeout` is optional argument - to simplify you may omit everything that is inside the brackets and the brackets - you will get `urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None, *, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)`.

`*` means that all the following arguments are keyword-only arguments - you must specify argument names.

Comment: Isn't everything *before* `*` (except `url`) also optional and keyword based?

Comment: also, why isn't there a comma between `]` and `*`?

Comment: @falsePockets `url` must be supplied, `data` and `timeout` are optional, all three may be suppliied without argument name, all arguments after `*` must be supplied with names. I guess there is no any difference between optional argument and argument with default value. The difference exists only in documentation because square brackets exist only in documentation. Comma is inside the brackets because  it should be omitted together with optional argument - a bit confusing I believe but essentially just documentation syntax rule.

Answer (score 1):

It is helpful to take a look at the actual [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/urllib/request.py), which says:

```
def urlopen(url, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
            *, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None):
// actual implementation
```

which is actually way more clear compared to the documentation.

Comment: So `[timeout, ]*,` is actually identical to `timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`? Why didn't they just write that? What's the difference?

Comment: @ falsePockets: Actually, it is identical to ``timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, *``. As @Poolka already pointed out, this seems to be purely documentation syntax and is NOT valid Python code (try to define a function like in the docs, and the interpreter will mark it as invalid). So in short: the difference is that one is valid code and the other is not, and they probably thought that the documentation syntax might be easier to understand. This is obviously debatable.