# Python OpenSSL connection failing handshake when using timeout

Tags: python, openssl

I'm seeing a weird issue when starting a TLS connection to any host. If I don't set any timeout on the socket, it works fine. If I do, it breaks *before* the timeout with a `OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError`. For example if I set timeout to 100, it will break after a second anyway.

For now I use a workaround of setting a timeout on connection, but then removing it before the handshake. How can I fix this to respect the timeout instead?

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(2)

ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(OpenSSL.SSL.TLSv1_METHOD)
ctx.set_options(OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_SSLv2 | OpenSSL.SSL.OP_NO_SSLv3)
ctx.set_verify(OpenSSL.SSL.VERIFY_NONE, lambda _a, _b, _c, _d, _e: None)
conn = OpenSSL.SSL.Connection(ctx, s)
conn.set_tlsext_host_name(hostname.encode('utf-8'))
conn.connect((ip, port))

s.settimeout(None)

try:
    conn.do_handshake()
except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:
    # this happens on every connection
```

Comment: What happens if you set conn.setblocking(1) ? Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675130/tls-connection-with-timeouts-and-a-few-other-difficulties) for a detailed answer

Comment: @SreekumarR This doesn't seem to make sense here. From the docs: `s.setblocking(1) is equivalent to s.settimeout(None)`. This is not what I need.

Comment: Also check WantReadError in the [openssl document](https://pythonhosted.org/pyOpenSSL/api/ssl.html) . Try using select() to make sure it is writable before calling do_handshake()

Comment: You're hitting a known Python + OpenSSL bug:
https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/168

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setblocking(1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Sockets are blocking by default. Also from documentation: `setblocking(True) is equivalent to settimeout(None)` - I do want timeout.