# How to limit the execution time of a function in C/POSIX?

Tags: c, posix, real-time, portability, preemption

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-limit-execution-time-of-a-function-call-in-python), I'd like to limit the execution time of a function--preferably with microsecond accuracy--in C. I imagine that C++ exceptions could be used to achieve a result similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-limit-execution-time-of-a-function-call-in-python/366763#366763) Python solution. Though it's not ideal, such an approach is wholly unavailable in plain C.

I wonder, then, how might I interrupt the execution of a function after a certain time interval in C on a Posix system? For relatively simple situations a bit of [silly business](http://troutwine.us/blog/telling_time.html) works just fine, but that adds a fair amount of code orthogonal to the problem solution. Let's say I have a function like so:

```
void boil(egg *e) {
    while (true)
    do_boil(e);
}
```

I want to run run boil on an egg*, interrupting it every 50μs to check do something like so:

```
egg *e = init_egg();
while (true) {
    preempt_in(50, (void) (*boil), 1, e);
    /* Now boil(e) is executed for 50μs, 
       then control flow is returned to the
       statement prior to the call to preempt_in.
     */
    if (e->cooked_val > 100)
        break;
}
```

I realize that pthreads could be used to do this, but I'm rather more interested in avoiding their use. I *could* switch between ucontext_t's in a SIGALRM handler, but the POSIX standard notes that the use of setcontext/swapcontext is not to be used in a signal handler and, indeed, I note differing behaviors between Linux and Solaris systems when doing so.

Is this effect *possible* to achieve? If so, in a portable manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to note that the general capability you're looking for here is called *cost enforcement*.  For example see this article by [Wellings](http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/RTSS.2005.14) or in [Leung, et. al.'s great book](http://books.google.com/books?id=Bz7DTDZQaGIC&lpg=SA12-PA9&ots=pHnUyFtZ55&dq=real-time%20operating%20system%20%22cost%20enforcement%22&pg=SA12-PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false).  The answers above are focused on achieving it in userspace; some RTOS or languages support it (not linux) as a general mechanism.

One example OS that provides this is the [AUTOSAR OS (spec linked)](http://www.autosar.org/download/AUTOSAR_SWS_OS.pdf).  Note that this OS provides *execution time enforcement*, which is slightly different from *deadline enforcement.*  Execution time enforcement keeps getting harder, as it relies on some ability to measure the actual cost expended (usually with hardware cooperation).  With the complexity of today's processors, it's difficult and costly to measure this — not to mention that the meaning of the measurements (due to nonlinear execution and all sorts of other cool stuff) are hard to interpret — and thus difficult event to compute a (worst- or common-) case estimate of a particular section of code's execution time.

Slightly off-topic, but Ada provides a more rigorous set of capabilities at the language level here, which doesn't help you, but you could figure out how these Ada requirements have been implemented in Linux.  The Ada language spec is unique in providing a rationale document, see the section on [real-time preemptive abort](http://adaic.org/standards/95rat/RAThtml/rat95-p3-d.html#6) as a departure point.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use threads, or have the function poll a timer (or a global variable set by `SIGALRM` handler), then save its state and exit when the allotted time has expired. Use of `ucontext_t` is deprecated and should never be used in new code, at all, much less from signal handlers.

Comment: Citation on `ucontext_t` deprecation?  I thought the associated functions just weren't widely implemented.

Comment: A quick google for `ucontext deprecated` finds things about particular vendors, especially Apple, marking them as deprecated. As for official deprecation, I don't have the citation right off, but I seem to remember SUSv3 deprecating some or all of the functionality due to the fact that C99 made some of the pointer cast constructs it requires undefined behavior. I'd have to look again to be sure though...

Comment: I'm supposing, then, that your answer is no. I will either have to poll, or introduce threads, in your estimation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I desire suddenly occurs to me: goto! I'll setup a jump point just after the function I wish to limit, set a timer and in the signal handler which deals with the SIG*ALRM simply jump to the instruction after the function.

Comment: If that's the effect you want, then why can't you just use `sigsetjmp()`/`siglongjmp()`?  Noting that `goto` does not in fact work across function boundaries.

Comment: Quite right, goto does have only function scope. While the use of \*jmp has a few deficiencies, it _mostly_ gets me where I want to go. I simply didn't think of it because "Goto is Harmful" had been for so long pounded into my head.