# Python, Timeout of Try, Except Statement after X number of seconds?

Tags: python, error-handling, timeout

I've been searching on this but can't seem to find an exact answer (most get into more complicated things like multithreading, etc), I just want to do something like a Try, Except statement where if the process doesn't finish within X number of seconds it will throw an exception.

EDIT: The reason for this is that I am using a website testing software (selenium) with a configuration that sometimes causes it to hang. It doesn't throw an error, doesn't timeout or do anything so I have no way of catching it. I am wondering what the best way is to determine that this has occured so I can move on in my application, so I was thinking if I could do something like, "if this hasn't finished by X seconds... move on".

Comment: When you say you're "using a website testing software" - do you mean you call it with some kind of `system` or pipe, as a child process, or what? (sorry if this is obvious for someone familiar with selenium, which I'm not)

Comment: well, it has its own API built for Python so its just importing some Selenium python classes and calling it from there, its (selenium) not a python app though as its written in javascript

Comment: Thanks for the answers, this helped point me in the right direction, which I think is to use processes and to kill it off based on certain conditions (i.e., if it doesn't update a DB with a value indicating it has 'finished' within a certain amount of time)

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question.  Please **update** your question. If your update includes all your comments, please delete the useless and confusing comments.  Please make the question itself complete.

Comment: What helped me was signal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call  The first linked so question is also about signal, but it's easy to overlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (and the question) isn't specific to the try/except statement. If you want to have an infinite loop that isn't infinite (but stops after a while), it probably shouldn't be infinite. For example, change it to use:

```
while time <= some_value:
```

Or add an extra check to the body of the loop, making it break when you want it to stop:

```
while True:
    ...
    if time > some_value:
        break
```

If that isn't possible (for example, because you don't control the loop at all), things get  significantly harder. On many systems you could use `signal.alarm` to have a signal delivered after a period of time, and then have a signal handler for `signal.SIGALRM` that raises your `TimeoutError` exception. That may or may not work depending on what the infinite loop actually does; if it blocks signals, or catches and ignores exceptions, or in any other way interferes with the signal handler, that won't work. Another possibility would be to not do the loop in the current process, but in a separate one; you can then terminate the separate process at your whim. It won't be easy to do anything but terminate it, though, so cleanup or recovery of partial work is very hard. (Threads aren't going to work at all, because there's no way to interrupt the separate thread doing the infinite loop.)

Comment: I shouldn't have used an example like that, sorry for the confusion... its not really about a loop (I just thought that would illustrate what I was trying to do with a Try, Except), I added the 'EDIT:' to the post to explain what I'm doing, its an external process that hangs sometimes so its not able to give feedback so I can move past it

Comment: Your post was definitely helpful though, its got me thinking of a way to do this using a memcache / db solution where I store a value for each loop and check back on that so I know if its finished or not, if not I just kill that "mini-process"

Comment: Using signals as a generic timeout mechanism in Python is dangerous.  See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682 (incidentally, one of many examples of SO questions marking wrong answers as solutions).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it without some sort of multithreading or multiprocessing, even if that's hidden under some layers of abstraction, unless that "process" you're running is specifically designed for asynchronicity and calls-back to a known function once in a while.

If you describe what that process actually is, it will be easier to provide real solutions. I don't think that you appreciate the power of Python where it comes to implementations that are succinct while being complete. This may take just a few lines of code to implement, even if using multithreading/multiprocessing.

Comment: thanks for the info... I updated the OP with info about what I am doing, its not that I don't want to use multithreading, just my case is kind of unusual I think (maybe / hopefully not?) so I can't figure a solution

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution if you are using UNIX:

```
import time as time
import signal

#Close session
def handler(signum, frame):
    print 1
    raise Exception('Action took too much time')


signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(3) #Set the parameter to the amount of seconds you want to wait

try:
    #RUN CODE HERE

    for i in range(0,5):
        time.sleep(1)
except:
    print 2

signal.alarm(10) #Resets the alarm to 10 new seconds
signal.alarm(0) #Disables the alarm
```