# Safe way to parse user-supplied mathematical formula in Python

Tags: python

Is there a math expressions parser + evaluator for Python?

I am not the first to ask this question, but answers usually point to `eval()`. For instance, one could do this:

```
>>> safe_list = ['math','acos', 'asin', 'atan', 'atan2', 'ceil', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'exp', 'fabs', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'hypot', 'ldexp', 'log', 'log10', 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'abs']
>>> safe_dict = dict([ (k, locals().get(k, None)) for k in safe_list ])
>>> s = "2+3"
>>> eval(s, {"__builtins__":None}, safe_dict)
5
```

But this is [not safe](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html):

```
>>> s_badbaduser = """
... (lambda fc=(
...     lambda n: [
...         c for c in 
...             ().__class__.__bases__[0].__subclasses__() 
...             if c.__name__ == n
...         ][0]
...     ):
...     fc("function")(
...         fc("code")(
...             0,0,0,0,"KABOOM",(),(),(),"","",0,""
...         ),{}
...     )()
... )()
... """
>>> eval(s_badbaduser, {"__builtins__":None}, safe_dict)
Segmentation fault
```

Also, using `eval` for parsing and evaluating mathematical expressions just seems wrong to me.

I have found [PyMathParser](http://www.bestcode.com/html/evaluate_math_expressions_pyth.html), but it also uses `eval` under the hood and is no better:

```
>>> import MathParser
>>> m=MathParser.PyMathParser()
>>> m.expression = s_badbaduser
>>> m.evaluate();
Segmentation fault
```

Is there a library available that would parse and evaluate mathematical expression without using Python parser?

Comment: Check out a similar question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647234/executing-mathematical-user-code-on-a-python-web-server-what-is-the-simplest-se

Comment: I saw that question, but executing user-supplied code (no matter how protected) seems unsafe to me. The example above just goes to show that it is extremely difficult (if at all possible) to protect `eval`. I am rather hoping for a math expression parser library. I updated the question to reflect that, thanks.

Comment: How do you define "user-supplied code". I feel that math expressions *are* user-supplied code.

Comment: @user1202136: Exactly - math expressions are user supplied code, so I don't want to eval() them or run them through Python parser any other way.

Comment: @PauloScardine: no, PyMathParser does NOT make a proper cleanup (I tested, same problem as above - will update question). I am not trying to reinvent the wheel, this is exactly why I am asking. :)

Comment: btw, an easier way to get the `function` and `code` types is `(lambda:0).__class__` and `(lambda:0).func_code.__class__` resp.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check out [Paul McGuire's pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing). He has written both the general parser and a [grammar for arithmetic expressions](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/fourFn.py):

```
from __future__ import division
import pyparsing as pyp
import math
import operator

class NumericStringParser(object):
    '''
    Most of this code comes from the fourFn.py pyparsing example
    http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py
    http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/message/view/home/15549426
    __author__='Paul McGuire'

    All I've done is rewrap Paul McGuire's fourFn.py as a class, so I can use it
    more easily in other places.
    '''
    def pushFirst(self, strg, loc, toks ):
        self.exprStack.append( toks[0] )
    def pushUMinus(self, strg, loc, toks ):
        if toks and toks[0] == '-':
            self.exprStack.append( 'unary -' )
    def __init__(self):
        """
        expop   :: '^'
        multop  :: '*' | '/'
        addop   :: '+' | '-'
        integer :: ['+' | '-'] '0'..'9'+
        atom    :: PI | E | real | fn '(' expr ')' | '(' expr ')'
        factor  :: atom [ expop factor ]*
        term    :: factor [ multop factor ]*
        expr    :: term [ addop term ]*
        """
        point = pyp.Literal( "." )
        e     = pyp.CaselessLiteral( "E" )
        fnumber = pyp.Combine( pyp.Word( "+-"+pyp.nums, pyp.nums ) + 
                           pyp.Optional( point + pyp.Optional( pyp.Word( pyp.nums ) ) ) +
                           pyp.Optional( e + pyp.Word( "+-"+pyp.nums, pyp.nums ) ) )
        ident = pyp.Word(pyp.alphas, pyp.alphas+pyp.nums+"_$")       
        plus  = pyp.Literal( "+" )
        minus = pyp.Literal( "-" )
        mult  = pyp.Literal( "*" )
        div   = pyp.Literal( "/" )
        lpar  = pyp.Literal( "(" ).suppress()
        rpar  = pyp.Literal( ")" ).suppress()
        addop  = plus | minus
        multop = mult | div
        expop = pyp.Literal( "^" )
        pi    = pyp.CaselessLiteral( "PI" )
        expr = pyp.Forward()
        atom = ((pyp.Optional(pyp.oneOf("- +")) +
                 (pi|e|fnumber|ident+lpar+expr+rpar).setParseAction(self.pushFirst))
                | pyp.Optional(pyp.oneOf("- +")) + pyp.Group(lpar+expr+rpar)
                ).setParseAction(self.pushUMinus)       
        # by defining exponentiation as "atom [ ^ factor ]..." instead of 
        # "atom [ ^ atom ]...", we get right-to-left exponents, instead of left-to-right
        # that is, 2^3^2 = 2^(3^2), not (2^3)^2.
        factor = pyp.Forward()
        factor << atom + pyp.ZeroOrMore( ( expop + factor ).setParseAction(
            self.pushFirst ) )
        term = factor + pyp.ZeroOrMore( ( multop + factor ).setParseAction(
            self.pushFirst ) )
        expr << term + pyp.ZeroOrMore( ( addop + term ).setParseAction( self.pushFirst ) )
        self.bnf = expr
        # map operator symbols to corresponding arithmetic operations
        epsilon = 1e-12
        self.opn = { "+" : operator.add,
                "-" : operator.sub,
                "*" : operator.mul,
                "/" : operator.truediv,
                "^" : operator.pow }
        self.fn  = { "sin" : math.sin,
                "cos" : math.cos,
                "tan" : math.tan,
                "abs" : abs,
                "trunc" : lambda a: int(a),
                "round" : round,
                # For Python3 compatibility, cmp replaced by ((a > 0) - (a < 0)). See
                # https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons
                "sgn" : lambda a: abs(a)>epsilon and ((a > 0) - (a < 0)) or 0}
        self.exprStack = []
    def evaluateStack(self, s ):
        op = s.pop()
        if op == 'unary -':
            return -self.evaluateStack( s )
        if op in "+-*/^":
            op2 = self.evaluateStack( s )
            op1 = self.evaluateStack( s )
            return self.opn[op]( op1, op2 )
        elif op == "PI":
            return math.pi # 3.1415926535
        elif op == "E":
            return math.e  # 2.718281828
        elif op in self.fn:
            return self.fn[op]( self.evaluateStack( s ) )
        elif op[0].isalpha():
            return 0
        else:
            return float( op )
    def eval(self, num_string, parseAll = True):
        self.exprStack = []
        results = self.bnf.parseString(num_string, parseAll)
        val = self.evaluateStack( self.exprStack[:] )
        return val

nsp = NumericStringParser()
print(nsp.eval('1+2'))
# 3.0

print(nsp.eval('2*3-5'))
# 1.0
```

Comment: The code looks nice! How would one replace the `cmp(a, 0)` best in Python 3?

Comment: @riddleculous: For Python3 compatibility, [replace `cmp(a, b)` with `(a > b) - (a < b)`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/49779/31627).

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Comment: very nice indeed. I was also planning to use pyparsing instead of mathparser. one question: how could you limit the numbers fed into the expression in order to limit the runtime? For example if I try to use 1000000000 ^ (1000000000 * 1000000000 * 1000000000) then it will blow up.

Comment: @SinanErdem: Instead of limiting the size of the numbers (which might be overly restrictive if the operation is, say, merely addition), you could run `nsp.eval` in a [separate process with a fixed timeout given in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8299131/190597). You might also want to [restrict the amount of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2308091/190597) the process can consume.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. and one thing caught my eye: why did you use caret (xor operator) instead of (**) for exponent operator?

Comment: That part of the code comes directly from [Paul McGuire's fourFn.py](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/fourFn.py). I guess the choice was made to bend the parser to the syntax used by most of the world instead of bending most of the world to the syntax used by Python.

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest using [`ast.parse`](http://docs.python.org/library/ast#ast.parse) and then whitelisting the parse tree.

```
tree = ast.parse(s, mode='eval')
valid = all(isinstance(node, whitelist) for node in ast.walk(tree))
if valid:
    result = eval(compile(tree, filename='', mode='eval'),
                  {"__builtins__": None}, safe_dict)
```

Here `whitelist` could be something like:

```
whitelist = (ast.Expression, ast.Call, ast.Name, ast.Load,
             ast.BinOp, ast.UnaryOp, ast.operator, ast.unaryop, ast.cmpop,
             ast.Num,
            )
```

Comment: That's a nice trick! I still prefer unutbu's solution because it is safe by design, but this is quite a nice trick - I guess that would make `eval` much much much safer. Thanks!

Comment: This approach won't protect against strings like `9**9**9**9**9**9**9**9` which try to compute extremely large numbers, effectively causing the program to hang indefinitely at 100% CPU.

Comment: @kaya3 To OP's defense, what's left after this safety check can only be resource-demanding executions. You may slow down the whole machine which could be bad, but not as bad as erasing the disk for good.

Answer (score 2):

I built upon a few posts here to make an evaluator class. Also used
[eval example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/3457624) which I basically rewrote into a class object.

```
import sys
import ast
import operator as op
import abc

import math

class IEvaluator:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def eval_expr(cls, expr, subs):  # @NoSelf
        '''IMPORTANT: this is class method, overload it with @classmethod!
        Evaluate an expression given in the expr string.

        :param expr: str. String expression.
        :param subs: dict. Dictionary with values to substitute.
        :returns: Evaluated expression result.
        '''


class Evaluator(IEvaluator):
    '''Generic evaluator for a string expression. Uses ast and operator
    modules. The expr string is parsed with ast resulting in a node tree.
    Then the node tree is recursively traversed and evaluated with operations
    from the operator module.

    :implements: IEvaluator
    '''

    @classmethod
    def _get_op(cls, node):
        '''Get the operator corresponding to the node.
        :param node: Operator node type with node.op property.
        '''
        # supported operators
        operators = {
            ast.Add: op.add,
            ast.Sub: op.sub,
            ast.Mult: op.mul,
            ast.Div: op.truediv,
            ast.Pow: op.pow,
            ast.BitXor: op.xor,
            ast.USub: op.neg
        }
        return operators[type(node.op)]

    @classmethod
    def _get_op_fun(cls, node):
        # fun_call = {'sin': math.sin, 'cos': math.cos}[node.func.id]
        fun_call = getattr(math, node.func.id)
        return fun_call

    @classmethod
    def _num_op(cls, node, subs):
        '''Return the value of the node.
        :param node: Value node type with node.n property.
        '''
        return node.n

    @classmethod
    def _bin_op(cls, node, subs):
        '''Eval the left and right nodes, and call the binary operator.
        :param node: Binary operator with node.op, node.left, and node.right
            properties.
        '''
        op = cls._get_op(node)
        left_node = cls.eval(node.left, subs)
        right_node = cls.eval(node.right, subs)
        return op(left_node, right_node)

    @classmethod
    def _unary_op(cls, node, subs):
        '''Eval the node operand and call the unary operator.
        :param node: Unary operator with node.op and node.operand properties.
        '''
        op = cls._get_op(node)
        return op(cls.eval(node.operand, subs))

    @classmethod
    def _subs_op(cls, node, subs):
        '''Return the value of the variable represented by the node.
        :param node: Name node with node.id property to identify the variable.
        '''
        try:
            return subs[node.id]
        except KeyError:
            raise TypeError(node)

    @classmethod
    def _call_op(cls, node, subs):
        arg_list = []
        for node_arg in node.args:
            arg_list.append(cls.eval(node_arg, subs))
        fun_call = cls._get_op_fun(node)
        return fun_call(*arg_list)

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, node, subs):
        '''The node is actually a tree. The node type i.e. type(node) is:
            ast.Num, ast.BinOp, ast.UnaryOp or ast.Name.
        Depending on the node type the node will have the following properties:
            node.n - Nodes value.
            node.id - Node id corresponding to a key in the subs dictionary.
            node.op - operation node. Type of node.op identifies the operation.
                type(node.op) is one of ast.Add, ast.Sub, ast.Mult, ast.Div,
                ast.Pow, ast.BitXor, or ast.USub.
            node.left or node.right - Binary operation node needs to have links
                to left and right nodes.
            node.operand - Unary operation node needs to have an operand.

        The binary and unary operations call eval recursively.
        '''
        # The functional logic is:
        # if isinstance(node, ast.Num):  # <number>
        #     return node.n
        # elif isinstance(node, ast.BinOp):  # <left> <operator> <right>
        #     return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.left, subs),
        #                                     eval_(node.right, subs))
        # elif isinstance(node, ast.UnaryOp):  # <operator> <operand> e.g., -1
        #     return operators[type(node.op)](eval_(node.operand, subs))
        # else:
        #     try:
        #         return subs[node.id]
        #     except KeyError:
        #         raise TypeError(node)

        node_type = type(node)

        return {
            # Value in the expression. Leaf.
            ast.Num: cls._num_op,  # <number>

            # Bin operation with two operands.
            ast.BinOp: cls._bin_op,  # <left> <operator> <right>

            # Unary operation such as neg.
            ast.UnaryOp: cls._unary_op,  # <operator> <operand> e.g., -1

            # Sub the value for the variable. Leaf.
            ast.Name: cls._subs_op,  # <variable>

            ast.Call: cls._call_op

        }[node_type](node, subs)

    @classmethod
    def eval_expr(cls, expr, subs=None):
        '''Evaluates a string expression. The expr string is parsed with ast
        resulting in a node tree. Then the eval method is used to recursively
        traverse and evaluate the nodes. Symbolic params are taken from subs.

        :Example:
            >>> eval_expr('2^6')
            4
            >>> eval_expr('2**6')
            64
            >>> eval_expr('1 + 2*3**(4^5) / (6 + -7)')
            -5.0
            >>> eval_expr('x + y', {'x': 1, 'y': 2})
            3

        :param expr: str. String expression.
        :param subs: dict. (default: globals of current and calling stack.)
        :returns: Result of running the evaluator.

        :implements: IEvaluator.eval_expr

        '''
        # ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/3457624
        if subs is None:
            # Get the globals
            frame = sys._getframe()
            subs = {}
            subs.update(frame.f_globals)

            if frame.f_back:
                subs.update(frame.f_back.f_globals)

        expr_tree = ast.parse(expr, mode='eval').body
        return cls.eval(expr_tree, subs)
```

Here are some examples:

```
import sympy

from eval_sympy import Evaluator

# test case...
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')

expr = x * 2 - y ** 2
# z = expr.subs({x:1, y:2})

str_expr = str(expr)
print str_expr

x = 1
y = 2
out0 = Evaluator.eval_expr(str_expr)
print '(x, y): ({}, {})'.format(x, y)
print str_expr, ' = ', out0

subs1 = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
out1 = Evaluator.eval_expr(str_expr, subs1)
print 'subs: ', subs1
print str_expr, ' = ', out1

sin_subs = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}
sin_out = Evaluator.eval_expr('sin(log10(x*y))', sin_subs)
print 'sin_subs: ', sin_subs
print 'sin(log10(x*y)) = ', sin_out
```

Results

```
2*x - y**2

(x, y): (1, 2)
2*x - y**2  =  -2

subs:  {'y': 2, 'x': 1}
2*x - y**2  =  -2

sin_subs:  {'y': 2, 'x': 1}
sin(log10(x*y)) =  0.296504042171
```