# Python compiled eval?

Tags: python, dsl

my situation is as follows:

1. I have a large table like object which is accessed with a string key and integer index; i.e. lookup is like this:  `value = table.get("Key", index)` .
2. I would like to give the user the opportunity to enter an arbitrary algebraic expression involving the string keys. The code code should then iterate over the second index and evaluate the expression repeatedly.

So for user input like this: `"KeyA + 2*math.abs(KeyC)"` I would like to run python code resembling:

```
for index in index_list:
    answer = table.get("KeyA", index) + 2*math.abs(table.get("Keyc",index))
```

I guess can parse the expression using one of the Python Parser libraries I found on the internet, but it is not by any means clear to me how actually "run" the parsed code. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that there is something wrong with that for, you keep assigning results to the same variable.

Comment: If you get the input parsed into valid python code you can use eval()

Comment: Well I have thought about eval() - but I would like to do the looping over the second index on the 'outside'.

Comment: @M4rtini It's a bad idea to use eval, it can run arbitrary code, and is a vulnerability if user input allowed as source

Comment: @alko I was assuming he was gonna parse the input with the mentioned "Python Parser libraries". My assumption that this would give safe code might have been wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your end users can enter variables in figure brackets, `{..}`, you can use `str.format` to format your string

```
>>> expression = '{a}*{b}'
>>> values = {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30} 
>>> expression.format(**values)
'10*20'
```

Here values dictionary might be filled with `table.get` for all keys found in expression, for example with a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> regexp = re.compile('{(.*?)}')
>>> keys = regexp.findall(expression)
>>> keys
['a', 'b']
>>> table_get = lambda *x: np.random.randint(5)
>>> values = {k: table_get(k) for k in keys}
>>> expression.format(**values)
'1*4'
```

Then you can refer to [Safe way to parse user-supplied mathematical formula in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11952343/1265154) for **safe** expression parsing and evaluation.

Comment: Thanks - the expression.format() method seems viable. I'll use the Safe parse link you provided.