# Pass a formula as a function parameter in python

Tags: python, function

I want to pass a formula within a function parameter in Python where the formula is a combination of the other function parameters. In principle this would look like this:

```
myfunction(x=2,y=2,z=1,formula="x+2*y/z")
6
```

or more generaly:

```
def myformula(x,y,z,formula):
   return formula(x,y,z)
```

This would allow the user to choose any arithmetic expression in terms of x, y, and z without having to create a new function.

One of the possibility I foresee is to convert the string in line of code within the function. Anything possible like that in Python? Or any other ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a job for `eval`. Either way, there are many threads on the subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing functions with arguments to another function in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803616/passing-functions-with-arguments-to-another-function-in-python)

Comment: @Havenard No, that's not a duplicate

Comment: i'd use a lambda instead. eval is too dangerous

Comment: Thanks for all of these different solutions. @unubtu, the question is corrected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html), you could evaluate mathematical expressions:

```
import sympy as sy

def myformula(formula, **kwargs):
    expr = sy.sympify(formula)
    return expr.evalf(subs=kwargs)

print(myformula(x=2,y=2,z=1,formula="x+2*y/z"))
# 6.00000000000000

print(myformula(x=2,y=2,z=1,formula="sin(x+y-z)"))
# 0.141120008059867
```

But note that `sympy.sympify` does use `eval` which makes it unsafe to apply to arbitrary user input
since strings can be composed to [trick `eval` into executing arbitrary Python code](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

A safer alternative is to build a parser to parse a strictly limited mathematical expressions.
Here are a few examples

- [Parsing expressions using ast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9558001/190597)
- [Using Paul McGuire's pyparsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11952343/190597)

Comment: suggest `return expr.subs(kwargs)`

Comment: can evaluate `print(myformula(x=2,y=2,z=1,formula="x+2*y/z>0"))`

Comment: @Azat: Unfortunately, that changes the behavior of the second example.

Comment: @unutbu Also looking for an answer to this, and decided to look at documentation for more information. I noticed that the docs say that sympify makes use of "eval", and is therefore should be subject to the same scrutiny... Or I may be missing something, as I'm a beginning programmer: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html

Comment: Also, in case you are still active, what if "my formula" contains some additional arguments that don't pertain directly to the arithmetic expression you want to pass? Is that when I use one asterisk instead of two?

Comment: @rocksNwaves: Thank you for pointing this out. I was totally and utterly mistaken. (While [sympy uses `ast`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py) to parse expressions under the hood, I didn't realize it still falls back on calling `eval`). 
Here is the relevant [github issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12524) which may help those interested in following (or contributing to) sympy's progress on this issue.

Comment: I've edited the post to suggest some safe parsing alternatives, but unfortunately they are not as comprehensive in their ability to parse strings into evaluable mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Your "myFormula" isn't much different than a regular lambda expression, except with the added baggage of having to parse a string into executable Python.

```
(lambda x,y,z: x + 2*y/z)(5, 2, 10)
```

As such, you could simply define `myFormula` as

```
def myFormula(*args, formula):
    formula(*args)
```

and call it as

```
myFormula(5, 2, 10, lambda x, y, z: x + 2*y/z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a lambda function. Something like this might suit you:

```
def myFormula(x,y,z):
    return lambda x,y,z: x+2*y/z
```

This way you don't have to define a new function and you don't have to pass anything extra as an argument.

Extra info about lambda functions: http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html

http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda

Comment: The arguments `x`, `y`, and `z` passed to `myFormula` are ignored; the returned function is simply a function taking 3 parameters.