# Passing a function formula using sympify and evaluating it

Tags: python, sympy

I have seen and attempted to implement the following answer to a similar question to no avail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23687379/3696204

I have also reviewed the documentation for SymPy evalf, about halfway down on this article:
http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html

**My code:**

```
from sympy import sympify


def test_function(a, b, c, d, funct):

    f = sympify(funct)
    dx = 0.2
    J = int(2/dx)

    for i in range(J-1):
        x = -1 + (i * dx)
        print("f(", x, ") = ", f.evalf(x))

    print("Just for fun: ", a, b, c, d)

    return c + d


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(test_function(1, 2, 3, 4, funct="pow(x, 4) - 2 * pow(x, 2) + 2"))

    print(test_function(1, 2, 3, 4, funct="x**4 - 2 * x**2 + 2"))
```

**Results in:**

```
    f( -1.0 ) =  -0.e+0*pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 4) + 0.e+0
    f( -0.8 ) =  -0.e+0*pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 4) + 0.e+0
    f( -0.6 ) =  -0.e+0*pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 4) + 0.e+0
    f( -0.3999999999999999 ) =  -0.e+0*pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 4) + 0.e+0
    f( -0.19999999999999996 ) =  -0.e+0*pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 4) + 0.e+0
    f( 0.0 ) =  -0.e+0*pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 4) + 0.e+0
    f( 0.20000000000000018 ) =  -0.e+0*pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 4) + 0.e+0
    f( 0.40000000000000013 ) =  -0.e+0*pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 4) + 0.e+0
    f( 0.6000000000000001 ) =  -0.e+0*pow(x, 2) + pow(x, 4) + 0.e+0
    Just for fun:  1 2 3 4
    7 

    f( -1.0 ) =  x**4 - 0.e+0*x**2 + 0.e+0
    f( -0.8 ) =  x**4 - 0.e+0*x**2 + 0.e+0
    f( -0.6 ) =  x**4 - 0.e+0*x**2 + 0.e+0
    f( -0.3999999999999999 ) =  x**4 - 0.e+0*x**2 + 0.e+0
    f( -0.19999999999999996 ) =  x**4 - 0.e+0*x**2 + 0.e+0
    f( 0.0 ) =  x**4 - 0.e+0*x**2 + 0.e+0
    f( 0.20000000000000018 ) =  x**4 - 0.e+0*x**2 + 0.e+0
    f( 0.40000000000000013 ) =  x**4 - 0.e+0*x**2 + 0.e+0
    f( 0.6000000000000001 ) =  x**4 - 0.e+0*x**2 + 0.e+0
    Just for fun:  1 2 3 4
    7
```

Based on reading the documentation, have also tried `f.evalf(subs=x)`, `f.evalf(subs={x: x_i})` where I redefined my loop in terms of x_i. In the first case I get a complaint about "floats not being subscriptable", and in the second case I get a complaint saying that "x is not defined".

Ok, that's all of my efforts so far. If anybody is curious, I have programmed the Thomas Algorithm for solving tri-diagonal matrices and am now create a method that applies Thomas to solve a PDE with the initial conditions given by some some equation. I want to pass that equation to my algorithm so that initial conditions can be provided on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `sympify` is executed on an string, the substring "x" gets interpreted as a symbol, namely `Symbol("x")`. This object has nothing to do with any Python variables you may call x. Symbol names and variable names are different things.

To replace Symbol("x") by the Python variable  called `x`, you need

```
f.subs(Symbol('x'), x)
```

This `subs` is enough, floating-point evaluation happens automatically since you supplied a floating-point argument. Otherwise, `evalf` could be forced with

```
f.evalf(subs={Symbol('x'): x})
```

By the way, `f.evalf(x)` means: evaluate f returning x decimal digits; nothing to do with substitution.

#### Asides

Function names: `x**4` and `Pow(x, 4)` both work, but `pow(x, 4)` has no meaning for SymPy.

To see the difference between variable names and symbol names, try

```
b = Symbol("a") 
print(b)  # prints "a"
print(a)  # undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

After `sympify`ing, `f` is an expression. We can turn `f` into a sympy function using [`lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html):

```
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> f = lambdify(x, sympify("pow(x, 4) - 2 * pow(x, 2) + 2"))
>>> [f(0.2 * i) for i in range(5)]
[2.0, 1.9216, 1.7056, 1.4096, 1.1296]
```