# How to convert the string '100+20*50/10-9' to float value using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, floating, arithmetic-expressions

Haii friends

How can I convert the string expression value to float value
ex: `s1 = '100+20*50/10-9'` this `s1` convert to `float` value. Based on the arithmetic operator priority rule it should give 191. But the string expression is not convert to float.

I had use `float('100+20*50/10-9')` and it raises error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in 
>   ValueError: could not convert string to float: '100+20*50/10-9`

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685946/math-operations-from-string https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836866/safely-evaluate-simple-string-equation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Math operations from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685946/math-operations-from-string)

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to parse a calculation string to a value, you have to evaluate the string first. Like this:

`eval('100+20*50/10-9')`

Then you may convert it to a float like this `float(eval('100+20*50/10-9'))`.

---

**However**, if the calculation string looked like this `101+20*50/3`, thus returning `434,3333(3)`, then you should think of a better solution, parsing the values within to a float before doing the calculation. See the difference:

---

```
print float(eval('101+20*50/3'))            '434.0
print float(eval('101.0+20.0*50.0/3.0'))    '434.333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

Also using another method:

```
s = '101+20*50/3'

print("{:.8f}".format(eval(s)))

#ouput:

434.00000000
```