# I write the code in python to count digits of a number but It doesn't work for some numbers

Tags: python, math

In order to count digits of a number I write this code in python:

```
a=int(input('number: '))
count=0
while a!=0:
    a=a//10
    count=count+1

print('number has ',count,'digits')
```

It works well for inputs like `13,1900,3222,....` But It give an error for numbers like: `3^21, 2^3,3*4,...`

It say:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3**21'
```

3**21 is integer input So why it gives this erroer,and How Should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `int()` constructor accepts string representation of ints, which `2**5` is not, this is an math operation, you may use `eval` to compute that. I've add an additionnal variable `value` to keep track of the initial value and print it at then end

```
value = eval(input('number: '))
a = value
count = 0
while a!=0:
    a = a//10
    count += 1    
print(value, 'has', count, 'digits')
```

---

## ⚠️ CAREFULL [`eval is dangerous`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Neither `'3^21'` nor `'3**21'` are integers. They are *strings* with Python expressions that would evaluate to integers if the Python interpreter evaluated them.

```
>>> 3^21
22
>>> 3**21
10460353203
```

The `int` builtin only accepts strings such as `'100'`, `'22'` or `'10460353203'`.

(`int` also has a `base` argument that defaults to `2` and allows you to issue commands like `int('AA', 16)`, but it still does not allow you do pass the kind of string-expressions you are trying to pass.)

Comment: Thanks, But How Can I edit my code in order to accept inputs like 3**21 ,...?

Comment: @amirali See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836866/safely-evaluate-simple-string-equation).

Answer (score 0):

You must eval() the expression first if you want an integer

```py
eval('3**21')
# 10460353203
```

and to simply count digits (like digits number is string length) :

```py
num_digits = len(str(eval('3**21')))

print(num_digits)
# 11
```

**So your code could be :**

```py
a=input('number: ')
num_digits = len(str(eval(a)))

print('number has ',num_digits,'digits')
```

Comment: this version works with 3^21

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
a=input('number: ') # entered 3**21
if a.isalnum():
    a = int(a)
else:
    exec("a = {}".format(a))
count=0
while a!=0:
    a=a//10
    count=count+1

print('number has ',count,'digits')
```

Output

```
number has  11 digits
```

This code will cast a to int only if a contained only digits else it will execute python command to store the expiration that entered to expiration and not int.