# Python string to float - fraction convertion

Tags: python

I'm using some function and it requires float number to do some maths. When I try to convert a fraction (example: 3/4 or 6/4) I get
`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3/4'` How can I overcome this problem? Obviously `float("3/4")`  doesn't really work out great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely evaluate simple string equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836866/safely-evaluate-simple-string-equation)

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you are trying to do in details? Maybe there must be some other ways of solving the problem.

Comment: You could use the fractions module: `from fractions import Fraction` then `float(Fraction('3/4'))`

Comment: I'm trying to make a discord bot @Xua. But franctions module seems the best way so I'd call this subject closed. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Using the fractions module (@user3697625)

```py
from fractions import Fraction
string = "3/4"
floatfromstring = float(Fraction(string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = "3/4"
a = string.split("/")
out = float(a[0]) / float(a[1])
```

Alternatively, you could use the fractions module:

```
from fractions import Fraction
out = float(Fraction("3/4"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably inferior to other solutions, but a one-liner!

```py
result = eval("3/4")
```