# Python - Can you convert a whole string into numbers and symbols?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, calculator, converters

I would like to know it it is possible to convert a string made of numbers and symbols into actual numbers an symbols, for example `'(12+23)*4'` into `(12+23)*4`
script:

```
input = input('import calculation: ')

print(input)
```

Output ex:

```
3*5
```

Desired Output ex:

```
15
```

Thanks!

Comment: This was already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: Do not use `eval`. Maurice has a good answer. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836866/safely-evaluate-simple-string-equation

Answer (score -2):

you can use `eval` function directly, even if it's not recommended for security concerns.

```py
eval(input('import calculation: '))
```

One more advice, do not name your variable as builtin function or imported ones, you're crrently doing monkey patching.