# Malformed node in ast.literal_eval call

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

It is my understanding that `ast.literal_eval` works with literals, so why does this give me an error?

```py
import ast

ast.literal_eval("1+2")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/355/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1500, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/355/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/home-pc/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2023.2/scratches/scratch.py", line 3, in <module>
    ast.literal_eval("(1+2)")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ast.py", line 110, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ast.py", line 109, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ast.py", line 83, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ast.py", line 74, in _convert_num
    _raise_malformed_node(node)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ast.py", line 71, in _raise_malformed_node
    raise ValueError(msg + f': {node!r}')
ValueError: malformed node or string on line 1: <ast.BinOp object at 0x7f85e1b73a00>
python-BaseException
```

Comment: Because `1+2` is not a literal value but a binary expression.

Comment: ok, how can I have a 3 from that string without using `eval`

Comment: It says in the documentation: *This can be used for evaluating strings containing Python values without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.* Link: https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Comment: Without using `eval()`, or related infrastructure, I believe you'll have to parse it and evalute it using your own code. Could it be an option to verify the form is safe (e.g. using a regex), and then using `eval()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely evaluate simple string equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836866/safely-evaluate-simple-string-equation)

Comment: It doe for numerical ones. but I also have string comparisons. :/

Answer (score 2):

In `ast.literal_eval()`, the `+` operator only works for complex numbers starting with Python 3.7, see:

- Issue: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/75959
- Fixing commit: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/d8ac4d1d5ac256ebf3d8d38c226049abec82a2a0

(In other words, the fact it did happen to work with other expressions had been a bug.)

You might want e.g. https://github.com/valohai/leval (disclaimer: my code) or https://pypi.org/project/pure-eval/ instead.

Answer (score 2):

From `Python 3.7`

`ast.literal_eval()` will not do addition.

you will get ValueError: malformed node or string

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

> Evaluate an expression node or a string containing only a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, None and Ellipsis.

> This can be used for evaluating strings containing Python values without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.