# How to turn strings into operations?

Tags: python, string, polynomials, operation

I recently tried to find polynomials with given points and stumbled upon the problem that I can’t use strings like normal mathematical operations: `"3 + 1" + "2 + 1"` because it will return `"3 + 12 + 1"`. I than tried to just iterate over the string but had the next difficulty that I cant just unstringify operations like `"+"` or `"-"`.

Does anyone know how to do solve the problem?

Comment: What problem? What would you expect and why?

Comment: What about sympy? https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#module-sympy.polys

Comment: you can translate from strings to operator functions, the latter are found here https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.add

Answer (score 1):

## **eval() is very dangerous**

It can execute any commands, including unsafe or malicious strings.

**Use Pyparsing** (more info [here](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) and another question and example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951701/safe-way-to-parse-user-supplied-mathematical-formula-in-python)).

Another option is the ast module (good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)). If you want more functionality, ast can open up more commands, but pyparsing should work well.

A third, more lightweight option is [this single file parser](https://github.com/louisfisch/mathematical-expressions-parser)

Answer (score 0):

If this calculation will exist purely within the code, with the user having *no direct access*, then you can use `eval()`.

Example:

```
print(eval("3 + 4"))
```

Output:

```
7
```

The point of `eval()` is to execute Python code that is stored as a string. If the user is inputting values to be used within an `eval()` statement, you should absolutely do some error-checking to make sure the user is inputting numbers. If your program was intended to be released for commercial use, say, you run the risk of a user inputting Python code that can be executed using `eval()`.