# Python kill thread

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep

I'm trying to kill a thread in python. An exception would be the preferred way to do it, as a graceful exit of the run method of the thread through a try:except: pair would allow to close resources.

I tried : [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) , but is specifies that is doesn't work while the code is executing a system call (like time.sleep). Is there a way to raise an exception in another thread (or process, in don't mind,) that work no mater what the thread is executing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, raising asynchronous exceptions is difficult to handle properly.  This is because, rather than having single, specific points of code where an exception may be generated--and therefore where exception handling needs to be tested--instead, an exception may be generated after *any* bytecode instruction.  This makes it much harder to implement and fully test exception handling.

That said, it can be done--but, presently, not safely in Python.  Raising an exception asynchronously in Python is dangerous, because you might raise it *during an exception handler*, which will raise another exception and prevent cleanup from occurring properly.  See my answer at [How to limit execution time of a function call in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682).

It's possible to signal some forms of sleep to cancel, but there's no general infrastructure for this in Python.  You're much better off either avoiding the need to kill a thread, or moving the thread to a *process*, where you can send a signal to the whole process and exit cleanly.