# Run a python function every second

Tags: python

What I want is to be able to run a function every second, irrelevant of how long the function takes (it should always be under a second). I've considered a number of options but not sure which is best.

If I just use the delay function it isn't going to take into account the time the function takes to run.

If I time the function and then subtract that from a second and make up the rest in the delay it's not going to take into account the time calculations.

I tried using threading.timer (I'm not sure about the ins and outs of how this works) but it did seem to be slower than the 1s.

Here's the code I tried for testing threading.timer:

```
def update(i):
    sys.stdout.write(str(i)+'\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print i
    i += 1
    threading.Timer(1, update, [i]).start()
```

Is there a way to do this irrelevant of the length of the time the function takes?

Comment: Another solution of mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/10718961/709852 should work for this. Actually, the solution is better suited since the timing resolution seems to be lower and it will likely work cross platform.

Comment: do you want it to loop in a background thread or in the main thread?

Comment: related: [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/474528/4279)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will do it, and its accuracy won't drift with time.

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
interval = 1
for i in range(20):
    time.sleep(start_time + i*interval - time.time())
    f()
```

Comment: Busy wait loops are now generally looked down upon for the reason you state...even if they appear to work.

Comment: Just replaced it with a sleep to improve that.

Comment: to avoid subtracting close floating point numbers, you could [use `time.sleep(1 - time.monotonic() % 1))` here for the same effect (to avoid drift)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35687118/4279).

Answer (score 7):

The approach using a threading.Timer (see code below) should in fact not be used, as a new thread is launched at every interval and this loop can never be stopped cleanly.

```
# as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393759/1025391
def update(i):
  threading.Timer(1, update, [i+1]).start()
  # business logic here
```

If you want a background loop it is better to launch a new thread that runs a loop as described in the other answer. Which is able to receive a stop signal, s.t. you can `join()` the thread eventually.

[This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498038/improve-current-implementation-of-a-setinterval-python/22498708#22498708) seems to be a great starting point to implement this.

Comment: Seems wrong [according to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393612/run-certain-code-every-n-seconds/3393759#comment92673741_3393759)

Comment: @lucid_dreamer The reasoning about recursion depth is incorrect (new threads don't increase recursion depth). But I agree that this is not how one would implement this ideally. Reasons being launching new threads over and over again, and the inability to stop the loop eventually.

Comment: I see. However still strange that he reported a quoted error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".

Answer (score 6):

if `f()` always takes less than a second then to run it on a one second boundary (without a drift):

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(1 - time.monotonic() % 1)      
    f()
```

The idea is from [@Dave Rove's answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251804/4279).

To understand how it works, consider an example:

1. `time.monotonic()` returns `13.7` and `time.sleep(0.3)` is called
2. `f()` is called around (±some error) `14` seconds (since `time.monotonic()` epoch)
3. `f()` is run and it takes `0.1` (< 1) seconds
4. `time.monotonic()` returns around `14.1` seconds and `time.sleep(0.9)` is called
5. Step 2. is repeated around `15` seconds (since `time.monotonic()` epoch)
6. `f()` is run and it takes `0.3` (< 1) seconds (note: the value is different from Step 2.)
7. `time.monotonic()` returns around `15.3` and `time.sleep(0.7)` is called
8. `f()` is called around `16` seconds and the loop is repeated.

At each step `f()` is called on a one second boundary (according to `time.monotonic()` timer). The errors do not accumulate. There is no drift.

See also: [How to run a function periodically in python (using tkinter)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609843/4279).

Answer (score 1):

How about this: After each run, sleep for `(1.0 - launch interval)` seconds. You can change the terminate condition by changing `while True:`. Although if the your function takes more than 1 second to run, this will go wrong.

```
from time import time, sleep

while True:
    startTime = time()
    yourFunction()
    endTime = time()-startTime
    sleep(1.0-endTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Threading may be a good choice. The basic concept is as follows.

```
import threading

def looper():    
    # i as interval in seconds    
    threading.Timer(i, looper).start()    
    # put your action here
    foo()

#to start 
looper()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Jupyter Notebook, you can make use of `ipywidgets.Play` widget's observe method to run a function after certain interval without blocking and keeping code in the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to recommend the following code. You can replace the True with any condition if you want.

```
while True:
time.sleep(1) #sleep for 1 second
func()    #function you want to trigger
```

---

Tell me if it works.