# High Resolution Timer in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to use an high resolution timer in python and if yes, what API do I need to use?

I want to create a midi clock. If I calculate the needed accuracy for the worst case, I get for 240bpm and a grid of 32T -> 10,4 ms. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

An possible answer to the question - but only for Windows - can be found here:

[How to implement high speed, consistent sampling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717589/how-to-implement-high-speed-consistent-sampling)

The trick is to use the multimedia timers, that have a minimum resolution of 1ms:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/multimedia-timers

Edit:

I use the mmtimer-class from the answer above, but I change the test function to record the events into an numpy record for further investigation:

```
ms = 25 # interval in ms
record_duration = 1

x = np.zeros(100000, dtype=np.float) # enough memory for recording events
count = 0

def tick():
    global count
    global x
    t = time.perf_counter()
    x[count] = t * 1000
    count += 1

t1 = mmtimer(ms, tick)
t1.start(True)
time.sleep(record_duration)
t1.stop()

start_time = x[0]
for i in range(count):
    x[i] -= start_time
    print("{0:.3f}".format(x[i]), "{0:.3f}".format(x[i] - i*ms))
```

Output:

```
0.000 0.000
24.622 -0.378
49.390 -0.610
75.090 0.090
99.207 -0.793
124.401 -0.599
149.167 -0.833
174.550 -0.450
200.112 0.112
225.008 0.008
249.212 -0.788
275.106 0.106
299.707 -0.293
324.156 -0.844
349.960 -0.040
374.333 -0.667
399.455 -0.545
424.175 -0.825
449.152 -0.848
474.053 -0.947
499.657 -0.343
524.595 -0.405
549.784 -0.216
574.261 -0.739
599.254 -0.746
624.142 -0.858
650.043 0.043
674.987 -0.013
699.720 -0.280
724.398 -0.602
749.914 -0.086
774.612 -0.388
799.372 -0.628
824.491 -0.509
849.886 -0.114
874.204 -0.796
900.226 0.226
924.123 -0.877
950.098 0.098
975.054 0.054
999.169 -0.831
```

In my oppinion the timer is good enough for build a midi clock on it. But there must be some logic to deal with the ms-grid. For example, if you use the timer with 19ms, you have around 131,6bpm. But if you use it with 18ms, you are at about 138,9bpm. The simple way will not work well.

Comment: what is the solution for linux python high performance  timer?