# Python: SIGALRM and setitimer in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, setitimer

The following code works in Unix, but i would like to transfer it to a Windows OS. The problem is that in Windows `signal.SIGALRM` and `signal.setitimer` don't work. I would really appriciate if someone could help me.

```
def handler(signum, frame):
   counter += 1
   print(counter)


signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, UPDATE_INTERVAL, UPDATE_INTERVAL)


for i in xrange(10):
    # Wait for signal to be received
    signal.pause()

# Print the stop time, in case you wanted to know.
_initTime()
print "Stop:", _now()

signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0)
```

Comment: see this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420422/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm) and answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: windows equivalent of SIGALRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420422/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm)