# Missing SIGALRM from signal.py

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to implement SIGALRM in python, but when I run the code, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIGALRM'
```

When I check the autocomplete options, the attributes of signal all populate the list (except for SIGALRM), so signal.py is obviously getting read at some level...

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Any particular platform?

Comment: Windows, running in a WinPy environment

Comment: Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420422/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm), Windows does not support `signal.SIGALRM`. The accepted answer there provides something that might work; I haven't tested it.