# Timing out a function in windows(python)

Tags: python

I want to implement a function which should be able to timeout a function after particular time.

In Linux, SIGALRM is there to use, but in windows i could not find any thing like that.

Is there any way i can achieve this in windows?
Can it be done without decorator??

Please Note Am a newbie in python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout on a function call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't something natively built into windows. What you can do is a workaround whereby you create your own thread handler.

[Described in a previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420422/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm)