# Python and 90 millisecond timeout

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to limit execution time of a function call in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-limit-execution-time-of-a-function-call-in-python)

I have a function that needs a 90ms timeout.  How can I cause an exception or a break or whatever if that limit is reached with extreme accuracy?

Thanks

Comment: Old question, but wanted to note that the linked duplicate question's accepted answer can only handle integer seconds.

Answer (score 0):

have a thread execute in the background that waits for approximately(can't do it accurately) 90 ms and then set an atomic boolean value to break the "wait" loop.

Comment: [threading.Event](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#event-objects) could be used to set the "bool".