# How can I limit the maximum running time for a unit test?

Tags: python, pytest

I am currently running some unit tests that might either take a long time before failing or run indefinitely. In a successful test run they will always complete within a certain amount of time.

Is it possible to create a pytest unit test that will fail if it does not complete within a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

you can install the pytest-timeout plugin and then mark your test functions with a timeout in seconds.

```
@pytest.mark.timeout(300)
def test_foo():
   pass
```

Look at the plugin download and usage instructions at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-timeout

Comment: is this doable without installing an extra package?

Comment: @Gulzar if you really need to you could vendor in this dependency or write a similar decorator yourself.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in my case: but admittedly I am using pytest-qt and the cause of the "hang" is a `QMessageBox` calling `question`, which causes the test to just stop mid-flow if there is no user input. Maybe pytest-qt has something specific... ?

Comment: [pytest-timeout](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-timeout): 5 PRs pending, 53 forks, and currently broken build. I'd think hard before using it.

Comment: From [the readme](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-timeout): `(pytest-timeout) is not designed for precise timings or performance regressions.` 

Answer (score 1):

Bash functionality can be used:

```
EXIT_CODE=0
TIME_LIMIT=60

timeout $TIME_LIMIT pytest ... || EXIT_CODE=$?

if [ $EXIT_CODE -ne 0 ]; then
    
    echo "Your error message to log"
    
    ...
    
    exit $EXIT_CODE
    
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a lightweight way that you can use in a `doctest` or directly in your script and without any extra dependency, inspired from [a question on how to limit execution time for a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-limit-execution-time-of-a-function-call)

```
import signal
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def time_limit(seconds):
    def signal_handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
    signal.alarm(seconds)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)

def efficiency_test(function, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        with time_limit(2):
            return (True, function(*args, **kwargs))
    except TimeoutError as e:
        return (False, None)
```

With example usage:

```
import signal
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def time_limit(seconds):
    def signal_handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
    signal.alarm(seconds)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)

def simple(a, b):
    return a + b

def complex_(a, b):
    for i in range(100000000):
        a += b
    return a

def efficiency_test(function, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        with time_limit(2):
            return (True, function(*args, **kwargs))
    except TimeoutError as e:
        return (False, None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(efficiency_test(simple, 1, 2))
    print(efficiency_test(complex_, 1, 2))
```

With output:

```
(True, 3)
(False, None)
```