# Can I add memory limits for Python unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Context: I'm developing for AWS Lambda. There you have time and memory limitations ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html)). I want to check in my unit tests if I might break those.

I have seen [`pytest-timeout`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-timeout) for limiting the time of a test in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19527320/562769) and I will use it for the time restrictions.

Is there something similar for memory?

Something like

```
@pytest.mark.max_memory_kb(128000)
def test_foo():
   pass
```

Comment: `man setrlimit(3)`?

Comment: @el.pescado Can I use `rlimit` in a unit test?

Answer (score 1):

Thos are work-arounds I found.

### sys.getsizeof(object)

```
from unittest import TestCase
import sys

class AgentAPITests(TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        return_value = foo()
        size = sys.getsizeof(return_value)
        max_bytes = 1337
        self.assertLess(size, max_bytes)
```

Drawback: It does not catch what is happening in between. For this reason I will not accept this answer.

### memory_profiler

This is not a unit test, so I will not accept this either.

I found something similar [here](https://vknight.org/unpeudemath/python/2016/09/26/Profiling-and-reducing-memory-consumption-in-python.html) using [`memory_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# core modules
from memory_profiler import profile

# internal modules
import foo


precision = 10
fp = open('memory_profiler_basic_mean.log', 'w+')


@profile(precision=precision, stream=fp)
def test():
    return_val = foo.bar()
    print(return_val)

test()
```

which creates such a log file:

```
Filename: foobar.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    14  51.6640625000 MiB  51.6640625000 MiB   @profile(precision=precision, stream=fp)
    15                             def test():
    16  52.2968750000 MiB   0.6328125000 MiB       return_val = foo.bar()
    17  52.2968750000 MiB   0.0000000000 MiB       print(return_val)
```

Hence I can see that the function needs `51.6 MiB`. If I could use that in a unit tests, my problem would be solved.

Here are questions going in this manual, non-unit test direction:

- [How do I profile memory usage in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/552744/562769)
- [Which Python memory profiler is recommended?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/110259/562769)

[`guppy`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/guppy/) seems to be usually used.

Comment: Using `sys.getsizeof` is not a reliable way to measure memory impact. Suppose class `A` creates an object with a single empty list as an attribute `.data`. So `a = A()`, then `a.data` is `[]`. Now, consider `a1, a2 = A(), A(); a1.data.extend(range(100000)); print(*map(sys.getsizeof, (a1, a2)))`