# How can I mark tests as "long" and skip them?

Tags: python, pytest, python-decorators, tox

I usually run my tests with `tox` which calls `pytest`. This setup works fine in many projects. In some projects, however, I have some tests which take long (several minutes). I don't want to run them every time. I would like to decorate the tests as long.

Something like this:

```
$ tox --skip-long
```

and

```py
# core modules
import unittest

class Foo(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_bar(self):
        ...

    @long
    def test_long_bar(self):
        ...

How can I do this?
```

Comment: A related question is how to skip tests if they are taking too long: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19527320/how-can-i-limit-the-maximum-running-time-for-a-unit-test

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found half of the answer [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html):

```
@pytest.mark.long
```

and execute

```
pytest -v -m "not long"
```

To run it on tox ([source](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/04/14/tox-tricks-and-patterns/)):

```
tox -- -m "not long"
```

The output then looks like this:

```
============================ 2 tests deselected ==================================
========== 20 passed, 2 deselected, 7 warnings in 151.93 seconds =================
```

Comment: Thanks! Works out of the box for me, though I also followed the documentation's suggestion to register the mark in `pytest.ini` or `pyproject.toml`: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/mark.html

Comment: Can you please explain here what is `-v -m`?

Comment: V is for verbose an m is for selecting a mark