# timeout function in socket program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeout, settimeout, python-sockets

I am using `settimeout()` function in such way:

```
import socket

s.connect((host,port))

s.settimeout(1)   #a
try:
    while True:
        s.settimeout(0.030)    #b
        try:
            code
        except socket.timeout:
            code
            break
except socket.timeout:
    print('over')
```

my code is in this form. Now timeout at a is not working but timeout at b is working because the code in timeout at b is executing

My project is to run further program for almost 1 sec but it is moving in continuous loop. I know it is because of while True but the code under loop should run continuously for 1 sec

If anyone have another method or tricks are heartily welcome

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

```
import socket

s.connect((host,port))
s.settimeout(1)
#a
try:
  while True:
      s.settimeout(0.030) 
      #b
      try:
        # code...
      except socket.timeout:
          # code... 
          break
except socket.timeout:
  print('over')
```

You are trying to limit the time of each request in inside the loop to 0.03 seconds, and the complete process to 1 second.
If so, you cannot limit the running time of the whole loop by setting the timeout socket, since it refers to a single socket operation.

You might consider using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601168/2326788).