# Exit try attempt after a given time in Python

Tags: python, timer, timeout, exit

I have a function which sends a request to a server. But sometimes the server doesn't reply and my code doesn't seem to continue. Now I wanted to implement, that the code continues to run, if no reply is received after a given amount of time. Below the code:

```
for attempt in range (3):
    try:
        print('Attempt: ' + str(attempt+1))
        print('DUT: ' + str(x))
        time.sleep(1)
        response = request("http://" + ipEntry.get() + port, "temperature_test", x)
        time.sleep(1)
        print(response.text)
        print(response.data.result)
        answer = response.data.result
        logFile.write(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S\t\t") + str(x) + "\t\t" + str(answer) + "\t\t" + str(readVoltage()) + "\t\t" + str(readCurrent()) + "\n")               
    
    except:
        print('An error occured!')
    else:
        if (response.data.result==False):
            print("Attempt " + str(attempt + 1) + " failed!")
        else:
            break
else:
                print('All 3 attempts failed')
```

Is it possible to start a counter after the beginning of this function and check with an "if" statement if it has elapsed?

Thanks for any hints and best regards!

Comment: i think what you're trying to find is the `continue` [keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_continue.asp#:~:text=The%20continue%20keyword%20is%20used,continues%20to%20the%20next%20iteration.) you can search about that

Comment: By any chance you are using request library because it has a parameter for that https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Comment: I don't know which module/library you are using for the request, but there is probably a `timeout` parameter.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the comments! I am using: "from jsonrpcclient import requests".

Comment: I checked the documentation ( https://jsonrpcclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html ) but couldn't find a timeout feature...

Comment: @Philipp i think there is a mention in their [github repository](https://github.com/bcb/jsonrpcclient/issues/129) about something similar. Another approach would be to have a look at [signals with an example described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-limit-execution-time-of-a-function-call-in-python)