# time limit for unresponsive method call

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a Python module that's a bit buggy. Sometimes, the function calls will take forever or even segfault. It will be a long while before upstrean gets to fix this. I need to find a way to run the method `ball()` with a time limit. Unfortunately, the suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/366682/353337) won't help since the process is unresponsive. Any hints?

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
import signal
import math
import time
from meshpy.geometry import (
    EXT_OPEN,
    GeometryBuilder,
    generate_surface_of_revolution,
)
from meshpy.tet import MeshInfo, build


# function that takes about 1min
def ball(h):
    r = 3.0
    polar_subdivision = int(math.pi / h)
    dphi = math.pi / polar_subdivision

    def truncate(val):
        return 0 if abs(val) < 1e-10 else val

    rz = [
        [truncate(r * math.sin(i * dphi)), r * math.cos(i * dphi)]
        for i in range(polar_subdivision + 1)
    ]

    geob = GeometryBuilder()
    radial_subdivision = int(2 * math.pi / h)
    geob.add_geometry(
        *generate_surface_of_revolution(
            rz, closure=EXT_OPEN, radial_subdiv=radial_subdivision
        )
    )

    mesh_info = MeshInfo()
    geob.set(mesh_info)

    build(mesh_info)
    # time.sleep(20)  # works


# from <https://stackoverflow.com/a/601168/353337>
class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass


@contextmanager
def time_limiter(seconds):
    def signal_handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutException("Timed out!")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
    signal.alarm(seconds)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)


with time_limiter(3):
    ball(0.02)
```