# (Python) Make a timer and skip code when timer runs out

Tags: python, timer

I want to make a quiz (5 questions) in which a timer (50 seconds) is running. The quiz should end either when the time is up or the user answers all questions.

I am pretty new to the coding world, but I already made the quiz (in German) with `if`, `elif`, `else`. So, the only thing is that I have no idea how to make the timer and make it skip other questions if the user is too slow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit execution time of a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682/how-to-limit-execution-time-of-a-function-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to answer without seeing your code. But if you set up a timer:

[https://www.udacity.com/blog/2021/09/create-a-timer-in-python-step-by-step-guide.html#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20simple%20timer,each%20component%20inside%20the%20module](https://www.udacity.com/blog/2021/09/create-a-timer-in-python-step-by-step-guide.html#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20simple%20timer,each%20component%20inside%20the%20module).

As the user answers the quiz you can store his answers in a `dict_of_answers = {}`. By adding it `dict_of_answers[question_number] = answer`.

At the end of the timer you can call the function that loads the result of the quiz by checking what is the current answers you have in `dict_of_answers`