# Set TTL for Supervisor jobs

Tags: python, supervisord

I've been using Supervisor for over a year now to run 40 jobs on a project.
Today, without any changes to the code or the server, two jobs got stuck, which caused some problems to the services I provide to my customers.

These jobs are very light, written in Python, and they usually process the workload in under 2 minutes.
However, they were stuck for hours.
Inside the code, I can't see anything that could've caused this.

Since I know 5 minutes would be more than enough to run the job, is there a way for me to set a TTL for these jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a way to configure this in Supervisor, but I was able to work around it by moving all my code inside a time_limit function as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601168/2011284).

Copying the code here:

```
import signal
from contextlib import contextmanager

class TimeoutException(Exception): pass

@contextmanager
def time_limit(seconds):
    def signal_handler(signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutException("Timed out!")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
    signal.alarm(seconds)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)


try:
    with time_limit(10):
        long_function_call()
except TimeoutException as e:
    print("Timed out!")
```