# How to limit the execution time of function calls in loop

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, python-multithreading

I have a loop which calls a function which sometimes hangs (example below). I found a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366682) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519) of how we might limit the execution time of a function call. However, they fail in loop situations as we might be midway through the next loop when the interrupt signal occurs. Is there any way to limit the execution time for the below code?

```py
def perhaps_long_exec():
  if random.random() < 0.5:
    while True:
      pass

for i in range(100)
  # limit execution time of below function call
  perhaps_long_exec()
```

We assume `perhaps_long_exec()` is an external function that cannot be modified. I have just given an example function as to what may be inside the function, but the function itself is a black box.

Comment: Why can't this be fixed in the function itself?

Comment: *while True: pass* is an infinite loop so if random.random() returns a value less than 0.5 your program will run indefinitely

Comment: @DarkKnight I think that's the point. Once it enters that infinite loop, the outer caller should terminate it after some cutoff

Comment: @roganjosh As written, it's impossible to do that as it's just one process. You could deal with it if it was a subprocess or thread but that's probably too complex for the author of this question

Comment: @DarkKnight it's tagged with `multithreading` so I'm pretty sure that the author knows it needs to be a separate process. The only thing missing is effort in the question to actually try action it

Comment: @roganjosh - I'm vaguely aware it needs threading, although I'm not sure how to do it (save for the linked answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiprocessing seems like a decent solution.
Make a new process for every loop and kill it if it's stuck.

```
import random
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def perhaps_long_exec():
    x = random.random()
    print(x)
    if x < 0.5:
        print('Stuck!')
        while True:
            pass
    else:
        print('Fine')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(100):
        p = Process(target=perhaps_long_exec)  # make process
        p.start()  # start function
        time.sleep(3)  # wait 3 secs
        if p.is_alive(): # check if process is still going
            p.terminate()  # kill it
            print('Killed')
```

Output:

```
> 0.26936380878403265
> Stuck!
> Killed
> 0.5185183414607246
> Fine
> 0.4361287927947891
> Stuck!
> Killed
```

Comment: What is the downside to this solution? It seems simpler than signal type solutions, yet the linked questions all have signal type solutions

Comment: The downside to this is that the main program will sleep for some constant time even if the subprocess terminates immediately

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check how much time has passed inside the function itself, I don't think you can interrupt the function from outside unless you use threads.

```
import time

SECONDS = 1
MINUTES = 60 * SECONDS
HOURS = 60 * MINUTES
TIME_LIMIT_IN_SECONDS = 2*HOURS

def perhaps_long_exec():
  if random.random() < 0.5:
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
      current_time = time.time()
      if current_time-start_time > TIME_LIMIT_IN_SECONDS:
        break
      pass

for i in range(100)
  # limit execution time of below function call
  perhaps_long_exec()
```

Comment: You NEED to be able to modify the called function, if you can't use @Scoffield answer. You could use a Thread's `setDaemon` to have a function running on a loop that checks an array, inside that array you have appended all the processes you've created, then check all of them for whatever cutoff you specify and terminate accordingly.

Comment: If we assume `perhaps_long_exec()` is an external function that cannot be modified, what is the downside to the answer by @Scoffield? It seems simpler than signal type solutions (such as @Diego-Torres-Milano answer), yet the linked questions all have signal type solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can use multithreading in conjunction with a semaphore like this:

```
from threading import Thread, Semaphore
from random import random
from time import sleep

TIMEOUT = 5

def perhaps_long_exec(s: Semaphore):
    if random() < 0.5:
        while not s.acquire(blocking=False):
            print('Do some work')
            sleep(1)

def main():
    s = Semaphore(0)
    (thread := Thread(target=perhaps_long_exec, args=(s,))).start()
    thread.join(TIMEOUT)
    if thread.is_alive():
        s.release()
        thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT:**

The question is tagged for multithreading. However, the *perhaps_long_exec()* function can be managed using multiprocessing in a non-cooperative way - i.e., it does not need to be modified.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from random import random
from time import sleep, time

TIMEOUT = 5

def perhaps_long_exec():
    if random() < 0.5:
        while True:
            print('Doing some work')
            sleep(1)
    else:
        print('Nothing to do')

def main():
    _start = time()
    (p := Process(target=perhaps_long_exec)).start()
    while (time() - _start) < TIMEOUT:
        if not p.is_alive():
            break
        sleep(1)
    else:
        p.terminate()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**CAUTION:**

Process.terminate() should be used with caution. Review [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: Does this still work if we cannot modify `perhaps_long_exec()`? Can we have a wrapper function?

Comment: @olivarb No. The *perhaps_long_exec()* function has to cooperate. This is because there is no support in Python for killing threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one process and without multithreading using signals

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import random
import signal
import time

def handler(*args):
    raise TimeoutError()

def perhaps_long_exec():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        time.sleep(600)
    
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
for i in range(100):
    # limit execution time of below function call
    try:
        signal.alarm(5)
        perhaps_long_exec()
    except TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout")
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)
```

Comment: Yes you can do it this way on Unix-like systems but not on Windows. The threading/semaphore approach in my answer is portable