Timeout Issue When Scraping Emails from Multiple URLs Using Python requests
I am working on a web scraping project using Python's requests library. The goal is to scrape emails from numerous URLs. To handle network delays, I set the timeout parameter as timeout=(10, 10).
However, when I run the script for multiple URLs, I encounter an issue where the program gets stuck on a request and does not respect the timeout settings. This results in the script hanging indefinitely, especially when scraping a large number of URLs.
Here’s the code snippet I’m using:
import requests  

urls = [  
    "http://example.com",  
    "http://anotherexample.com",  
    # ... more URLs  
]  
HEADERS={"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
for url in urls:  
    try:  
        response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, timeout=(10, 10))  
        if response.status_code == 200:  
            # Extract emails (simplified for demonstration)  
            print(f"Emails from {url}: ", response.text)  
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:  
        print(f"Timeout occurred for {url}")  
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  
        print(f"Error occurred for {url}: {e}")  

Despite using the timeout parameter, the script sometimes gets stuck indefinitely and doesn’t proceed to the next URL.
Steps Taken:

Tried reducing the timeout values to (5, 5) but encountered the same issue.
Ensured that the URLs are valid and accessible.

My Questions:

Why might the timeout not work as expected in this case?

How can I ensure that the script doesn't hang indefinitely when scraping a large number of URLs?


Any help or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:
Python version: 3.10.10
requests version: 2.32.3

if you are scraping multiple websites, then the first thing that you need to do it Threading or asyncio. the gain in speed will be large.

Some sites may have scraping protections. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/366763/2834978

the given code actually runs fine.  So it could be what @LMC says....  perhaps you can provide an example where the code fails.   In any event, with the answer posted, you may be able to handle such errors in a cleaner way (separate function).

@darren and anyone interested, see these awesome articles one anti-scraping techniques, baypass-cloudflare

This should work better:
It is optimal to use threading or asyncio for this task.
They would parallelise the process.
I personally find threading a bit easier (slightly less code - see below).
There are two functions:

scrape_website  (for scraping and handling that properly).
threaded_scraper  (deploy for multiple websites).

And then, Finally, the main body.
import threading
import requests

def scrape_website(url, results, lock):
    """Function to scrape a single website."""
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=10)
        response.raise_for_status()
        with lock:
            # Store the response text in a thread-safe way
            results[url] = response.text
            print(f"Successfully scraped: {url}")
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        with lock:
            results[url] = None  # Indicate failure
            print(f"Failed to scrape: {url}, error: {e}")

def threaded_scraper(urls):
    """Scrape multiple websites concurrently using threads."""
    threads = []
    results = {}
    # Lock for thread-safe access to results
    lock = threading.Lock()  

    # Create a thread for each URL
    for url in urls:
        thread = threading.Thread(
            target=scrape_website, 
            args=(url, results, lock)
            )
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for thread in threads:
        thread: threading.Thread
        thread.join()

    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # List of URLs to scrape
    urls_to_scrape = [
        "https://example.com",
        "https://httpbin.org/get",
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
        "https://www.python.org",
        "https://www.wikipedia.org"
    ]

    # Scrape the websites using threads
    scraped_data = threaded_scraper(urls_to_scrape)

    # Print the results
    for url, content in scraped_data.items():
        print(f"\nContent from {url}:\n{'[Success]' if content else '[Failed]'}")

I run the above in a jupyter notebook in VScode and get this:
Successfully scraped: https://www.python.org
Successfully scraped: https://www.wikipedia.org
Successfully scraped: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
Successfully scraped: https://example.com
Successfully scraped: https://httpbin.org/get

Content from https://www.python.org:
[Success]

Content from https://www.wikipedia.org:
[Success]

Content from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts:
[Success]

Content from https://example.com:
[Success]

Content from https://httpbin.org/get:
[Success]


This will create one thread for each URL in the list. If the list is long, this can lead to network contention. Better to use a pool of threads of some finite size

@SIGHUP,  yes,  there are a number of ways to tackle the problem.  I was also tempted to demonstrate asyncio but this satisfies the given question from the OP.

@SIGHUP,  the thread pool would be more efficient (reuse threads) and also controls the max threads as you have correctly pointed out. But would have less  granular control and an overhead for lighter-weight tasks.  So it is swings and roundabouts in that sense.

Unfortunately, this still doesn't answer why some of the requests are (apparently) blocking.

I ran the code in the question and it works, so it would be hard to tell in absence of a broken code example. This approach does allow the user the handle errors in a cleaner way (functional) if the (apparent) blocking did occur.

I am trying this type of possible option but it has not been solved. Because Read timeout does not occur I mean just stack. But the URL is accessible. Instead of the requests module in this situation, I used httpx, but it is work properly. I don't what is the problem in requests library.

If, as seems to be the case, you are specifying both connect and read timeouts, then indefinite blocking should not occur.
This doesn't directly answer the question but provides a reasonable (IMHO) pattern that you could adapt and "plug in" your own list of URLs to see what happens:
import requests
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import sys
import time

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
# too many threads can lead to network contention
NTHREADS = 4
TIMEOUT = 3.05, 15.05
CHUNK = 4 * 1_024

# Read this: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#advanced

def process(url):
    try:
        start = time.time()
        with requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, timeout=TIMEOUT, stream=True) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            # consume all content
            for _ in response.iter_content(CHUNK):
                pass
        duration = time.time() - start
        print(f"{url} -> {duration=:.4f}s")
    except Exception as e:
        print(url, e, file=sys.stderr)
    

def main():
    urls = [
        "https://example.com",
        "https://httpbin.org/get",
        "https://www.google.com",
        "https://www.python.org",
        "https://www.wikipedia.org",
        "https://www.bbc.co.uk",
        "https://www.foo.bar.zzz",
        "https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?bytes=5242880"
    ]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(NTHREADS) as executor:
        executor.map(process, urls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I am trying this type of possible option but it has not been solved. Because Read timeout does not occur I mean just stack. But the URL is accessible. Instead of the requests module in this situation, I used httpx, but it is work properly. I don't what is the problem in requests library

@MominurRahman "I mean just stack" - please explain. Did you try this exact code but with your list of URLs? What happened?

timeout for requests library is not for the whole process of a request.
Roughly, it includes two parts. The connect timeout and the read timeout.
Connect timeout is the seconds you will wait for your client to establish a connection to a remote machine call on the socket. It's about 21secs if you don't define a value as I tested (maybe not representative).
Read timeout is the time limit from the very time the connection has been established to a bytes data has been sent from the server. The time of receiving all those data is not included. If not set, request do not time out while receiving data. :P
Since you didn't give the example urls, I can't tell the problem exactly.
Here is a test code for you to understand the read timeout. This code will not raise a timeout exception, although it tooks 2.821713447570801 seconds, greater than 0.5.
import time
import requests

t1 = time.time()
url = 'https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?bytes=5242880'  # 5MB downloading test
r = requests.get(url, timeout=0.5)
t2 = time.time()

print("reqtimes: ", t2 - t1)  # mine is 2.821713447570801

To answer your second question, I suggest using signal to time out the whole process.
import time
import signal
import requests

class TimeoutException(Exception):
    """ Simple Exception to be called on timeouts. """
    pass

def _timeout(signum, frame):
    """ Raise an TimeoutException.

    This is intended for use as a signal handler.
    The signum and frame arguments passed to this are ignored.

    """
    raise TimeoutException()

time_out = 1  # you can set a timeout here
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _timeout)
signal.alarm(time_out)
t2 = 0
try:
    t1 = time.time()
    r = requests.get('https://speed.cloudflare.com/__down?bytes=5242880', timeout=time_out)
    t2 = time.time()
except Exception as e:
    t2 = t2 or time.time()
    print('timeout fired.')
finally:
    signal.alarm(0)
    print("reqtimes: ", t2 - t1)


I am trying this type of possible option but it has not been solved. Because Read timeout does not occur I mean just stack. But the URL is accessible. Instead of the requests module in this situation, I used httpx, but it is work properly. I don't what is the problem in requests library
